# Change color of button in a quiz depending on answer in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a quiz written in React Native. When the user presses the right answer, I want the button to become green before moving to the next question. If it's wrong, I want the right answer to become green and the pressed button to become red. I'm quite new to React and not sure how to change state of only a particular button. How it looks now, all buttons becomes red/green as I set the background color for all the buttons.

Quiz screen:

```
  state = {
    correctCount: 0,
    totalCount: this.props.navigation.getParam("questions", []).length,
    activeQuestionIndex: 0,
    answered: false,
    answerCorrect: false,
    btnColor: {backgroundColor: '#FFDD7C'}
  };

  answer = correct => {
    this.setState(
      state => {
        const nextState = { answered: true };

        if (correct) {
          nextState.correctCount = state.correctCount + 1;
          nextState.answerCorrect = true;
          nextState.btnColor = {backgroundColor: '#00ff00'};
        } else {
          nextState.answerCorrect = false;
          nextState.btnColor = {backgroundColor: '#ff0000'};
        }

        return nextState;
      },
      () => {
        setTimeout(() => this.nextQuestion(), 750);
      }
    );
  };

  nextQuestion = () => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const nextIndex = state.activeQuestionIndex + 1;

      if (nextIndex >= state.totalCount) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('QuizStatsScreen', {
          totalQuizCount: state.totalCount,
          correctQuizCount: state.correctCount
        });
      } else {
        return {
          activeQuestionIndex: nextIndex,
          answered: false,
          btnColor: {backgroundColor: '#FFDD7C'}
        }
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const questions = this.props.navigation.getParam("questions", []);
    const question = questions[this.state.activeQuestionIndex];

    return (
      <View>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.safearea}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{question.question}</Text>

            <ButtonContainer>
              {question.answers.map(answer => (
                <Button
                  key={answer.id}
                  text={answer.text}
                  onPress={() => this.answer(answer.correct)}
                  style={this.state.btnColor}
                  correct={this.state.answerCorrect}
                />
              ))}
            </ButtonContainer>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Button screen:

```
export const Button = ({ correct, text, style, onPress = () => {} }) => {

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[styles.button, {...style}]}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: They're all going green because you are setting a boolean to true (which is okay), however you are missing crucial info (i.e. which answer is the correct answer).  This should either be the id of the answer, or the option.  Which you also pass into your button and then compare the correct id to the current buttons id (or option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one more variable as  selectedId and in your state.
When your click on any answer then check if answer is right or wrong set answerCorrect true if right or false and then store your right and store answer.id to selectedId state.

```
                <Button
                 ....
                  style={               
                      answer.id === selectedId && answerCorrect ? 
                      styleForCorrectAnswer : 
                      answer.id === selectedId && !answerCorrect ?
                       styleForWrongAnswer :
                      styleForDefaultAnswer
                   }
                />
```

What we are doing here is first we check if our answer.id match with selected answer id and answer is right. If yes then we are giving styleForCorrectAnswer else we are checking here if answer.id and selectedId match and user's answer is wrong then we are applying styleForWrongAnswer else styleForDefaultAnswer

Comment: Sorry, but how do I store the selectedId to compare with?

Comment: when user click on perticuler button for answer selection then set your selected id there like onPress={() => this.answer(answer)} then you can use your answer.id in  answer function

Comment: ah, got it! Works with the button that is selected! Thanks for the extra explanation! Now to try to find out how to color the right answer if wrong answer has been selected :)

Comment: I added this.state.answered && answer.correct before defaultAnswer styling to show the correct answer when pressing any of the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Do something Like that change the state where you want and it will work

```
{this.state.correct
?
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={{backgroundColor:'green'}}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Correct</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
:
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>False</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
}
```